# SystemIcons default size

Tags: .net, icons

What is the default (i.e. native) size of a System.Drawing.SystemIcons icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get **32** on Windows XP.

```
System.Drawing.Icon SystemIcon = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Application;
Console.WriteLine(SystemIcon.Height);
Console.WriteLine(SystemIcon.Width);
```